# Change font rendering (non-antialiased) with pango

Tags: cairo, antialiasing, pango

How do I render a string with pango using custom antialiasing and hinting settings?

I tried `PangoCairo.set_antialias(cairo.ANTIALIAS_NONE)` (in pygtk), but it had no effect. I'd like to be able to change freetype's rendering parameters, like I can do via fontconfig/`fonts.conf`, but at runtime. (This is on Linux.) Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if understood you right, but I usually use [cairo_set_antialias ()](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-set-antialias) in my C-code, though I don't know an equivalent in PyGTK. As far as I understand it's Cairos' rendering settings that you should change to change an anti-aliasing and hinting of an output. At least I do this way.

Comment: The documentation you linked to says "Note that this option does not affect text rendering, instead see cairo_font_options_set_antialias()."

Answer (score 1):

In C you can turn off anti-aliasing when drawing with Pangocairo like this:

```
cairo_font_options_t *options = cairo_font_options_create();
cairo_font_options_set_antialias(options, CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_NONE);
pango_cairo_context_set_font_options(context, options);
cairo_font_options_destroy(options);
```

This can probably be adapted for PyGTK.