# How to set anti-aliasing mode for specific gtk+ application

Tags: gtk, pygtk, pygobject

I trying to write simple `gtk+` application with `pygobject` that using [gtk.TextView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html). In stock [demo code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/demos/gtk-demo/gtk-demo.py#n320)  I see that font sets up with `Pango`, but I can't find corresponding method for set up antialiasing-mode. By default font looks little ugly for me.

Does anybody know how to set anti-aliasing in gtk+ app (with python or pure C, Pango or other way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not easy. Many factors interact to get the final font glyphs on your screen.

Maybe one of the easiest ways to change antialiasing globally would be to reprogram `fontconfig`. [This article](http://udel.edu/~doke/antialiased_fonts.html) describes how to *disable* anti-aliasing, but it indicates where the config item is located.

Then, on a per-application basis, the actual work of drawing the characters is in the hands of [Pango](http://www.pango.org/), but Pango may be programmed to use Xft (fontconfig) or Cairo to do the actual drawing. In case of Cairo (which seems to gather popularity), the anti-aliasing is done *there*. There's [an article on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106659/change-font-rendering-non-antialiased-with-pango) here on stackoverflow. Basically there's a function in the Cairo library, called ['cairo_set_aliasing'](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-set-antialias)

**Edit**: Have a look at the XFCE window manager. In ths `Settings` | `Appearance` tool, you can change the anti aliasing 'globally', from 'none', 'slight', 'more' to 'full', and select subpixel in color or gray, horizontal/vertical and details. The code is contained in the `xfce4-appearance-settings` module of XFCE.

The aliasing setup is in `xfce4-settings-4.12.0.tar.bz2`, in `dialogs/appearance-settings/main.c`. I'm not sure if it actually activated there. I've quite a lot of work at the moment, but, if necessary can lend you a hand later.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I saw sublime-text has this feature. It can change aa mode to none, gray and subpixel. It seems like author used own rendering engine for it.

Comment: Of course, it's possible, but I don't think so. I've added some info to the original answer, on XFCE, which lets you change anti-aliasing.