# Render antialiased text with Pango

Tags: tesseract, pango, pangocairo

I'm trying to modify `text2image` from the Tesseract OCR training code to output antialiased text.

I've tried tried the suggestions from both [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310994/constantine-d) and [Constantine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197719/andreas) in this SO Question: [Change font rendering (non-antialiased) with pango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106659/change-font-rendering-non-antialiased-with-pango) but the output is always the same - lots of jagged edges:

[image]

Anyone know how to antialias the rendered text?

Answer (score 0):

`text2image` generates black&white (1 BitsPerPixel) images that why so do not see antialiased text.

Also, tesseract uses for training and OCR black&white images, so there is no sense to use/producing antialiased image with `text2image`...